# How can I remove ARC from iPhone project build for iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

Now I have a Xcode project which is built for iOS 5, but now i have to install it on an iPhone 3GS, which has a older iOS. I came to know that this is because I am using ARC in this project and it is not available in iOS 3.2. How can I remove ARC from my current project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want it disabled for the whole project, you need to go to the target's build settings and set it to No
[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]  very simple first go to targets in that go  "buldphases"-->compileSource--> here "**yourfile.m**"  --> set value 
     -**fno-objc-arc**(only particular files )

if u want remove ARC in entire project go to targets in that go  "buldsettings" ---> objective-c automaticrefcount :NO

[image]

Comment: Thank you, we can also remove ARC, edit>Refactor> Convert to Objective-C ARC--- Here we can edit the files wich has ARC enabled

Answer (score 1):

In XCode, there is a global compiler flag called `-fobjc-arc`. If you disable this (`-fno-objc-arc`), ARC will be disabled in your whole project. If only a few files don't support ARC, use the `-fno-objc-arc` flag on those files only. The last flag "wins", see  http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#general.

However, make sure that you know what you're doing! If the project was designed around ARC, there may not be any deallocation-code in there, including `dealloc` methods. Also, your properties might be unsupported (`strong`, `weak` etc.). You'll most likely end up in a complete mess.

Your best bet would be to just upgrade your 3GS.

Answer (score 1):

Go
Build Settings
make sure "all" option is selected
search for automatic you will find Objective-c Automatic Reference counting set NO